# Oracle Relational Database

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to implement a code that filters the number of customers who have checked more books than DVDs in a library. The query is supposed to display the customer name, total book checkouts and total DVD checkouts. 
[ERD with all the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzNgb.png)

**Here is my code that counts the total book checkouts and total DVD checkouts.**

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME||' '|| C.CUSTOMER_LASTNAME "CUSTOMER 
NAME",COUNT(*)"TOTAL CHECKOUTS"
FROM  CATALOG_ITEM CI
JOIN PHYSICAL_ITEM PI
ON CI.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = PI.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
JOIN TRANSACTION TI
ON PI.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID = TI.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID
JOIN LIBRARY_CARD LC
ON TI.LIBRARY_CARD_ID = LC.LIBRARY_CARD_ID
JOIN CUSTOMER C
ON LC.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME||' '|| C.CUSTOMER_LASTNAME,CI.TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I finally solved my problem. Using COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 'record' THEN 1 END), I was able to specify the record to be counted on each column.**

```
    SELECT C.CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME ||' '||C.CUSTOMER_LASTNAME "CUSTOMER NAME",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CI.TYPE = 'BOOK' THEN 1 END)"TOTAL BOOK CHECKOUTS",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CI.TYPE = 'DVD' THEN 1 END)"TOTAL DVD CHECKOUTS"
    FROM CATALOG_ITEM CI
    JOIN PHYSICAL_ITEM PI
    ON CI.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = PI.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
    JOIN TRANSACTION TI
    ON PI.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID = TI.PHYSICAL_ITEM_ID
    JOIN LIBRARY_CARD LI
    ON TI.LIBRARY_CARD_ID = LI.LIBRARY_CARD_ID
    JOIN CUSTOMER C
    ON LI.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID
    GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME ||' '||C.CUSTOMER_LASTNAME
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN CI.TYPE = 'BOOK' THEN 1 END) > COUNT(CASE WHEN CI.TYPE = 
    'DVD' THEN 1 END)
    ORDER BY C.CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME ||' '||C.CUSTOMER_LASTNAME;
```

Any alternative solution will be appreciated.